# Having trouble to understand how __str__ special method executes

Tags: python, class, oop, magic-methods

I am not able to explain the behaviour of the following code when running it in PyCharm:

```
class Empty:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        print('in!')
        return f'<{__name__}.Empty object at {hex(id(self))!r}>'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    e = Empty()
```

The output:

```
in!
in!
```

There is no output when running the code from the terminal like this `python .\my_script.py`. May someone have an explanation for this? Thanks!

Comment: Depends on how exactly you're running this, but it's probably PyCharm's debugger/variable inspector.

Comment: Thank you very much. The fact that the `__str__` method is internally triggered by the code editor makes sense!